# Send data to CRM using PHP cUrl

Tags: php, curl

I pass data into my CRM via link:

```
http://www.crmtool.net/lp_NewLead.asp?lp_CompanyID=12345&lp_Username=test&lp_Password=test&lp_SourceType=WEBBusinessTelecom&lp_UserField6=WebForm-AIIMS&lp_Company=Qwerty2&lp_ContactFirstName=Roland&lp_Phone=11111&lp_Email=test
```

But when I try to do it via PHP cUrl, it doesn't send to CRM:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "lp_SourceType" => "WEB - Business Telecom",
    "lp_UserField6" => "Web Form - AIIMS",
    "lp_UserField6" => "Web Form - AIIMS",
    "lp_Company" => $business,
    "lp_ContactFirstName" => $name,
    "lp_Phone" => $phone,
    "lp_Email" => $email,
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://www.crmtool.net/lp_NewLead.asp?lp_CompanyID=12345&lp_Username=test&lp_Password=test');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

How can I pass data via cUrlin this case?

Comment: please provide the html response that a you get!

Answer (score 0):

The given URL seem to be GET method.
Have you try to change it back to GET method and put all of your data array back to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
// http://www.crmtool.net/lp_NewLead.asp?lp_CompanyID=12345&lp_Username=test&lp_Password=test&lp_SourceType=WEBBusinessTelecom&lp_UserField6=WebForm-AIIMS&lp_Company=Qwerty2&lp_ContactFirstName=Roland&lp_Phone=11111&lp_Email=test
$data = array(
    'lp_CompanyID' => '12345',
    'lp_Username' => 'test',
    'lp_Password' => 'test',
    'lp_SourceType' => 'WEBBusinessTelecom',
    'lp_UserField6' => 'WebForm-AIIMS',
    'lp_Company' => 'Qwerty2',
    'lp_ContactFirstName' => 'Roland',
    'lp_Phone' => '11111',
    'lp_Email' => 'test',
);

$url = 'http://www.crmtool.net/lp_NewLead.asp?' . http_build_query($data);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $ch,
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

As your say you may pass data throught the link. So your CRM accept data via GET parameters, not via json-request.

Comment: Hello . Thank yyou, I try the code . It is not working for me :(